# ASP.NET Session

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net Session is having same value for differnt browsers....Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

If by different browsers you mean two instances of IE on the same machine, then the answer is that sessions are cookie based (eg. the session id is stored in a cookie) and several instances of the same browser share cookies.

Answer (score 1):

A session only lives until the browser is closed.

So you either

- set the value to be the same in differnt browsers
- you are not using sessions
- Retreive the session using an URL or cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the same browser twice, the second instance might use the same cookies as the first - so you get the same session.
This is very browser dependent.